# Is it possible to remove Account Linking from a project?

Tags: actions-on-google

My action was rejected during review because it does not support account linking / GSI (Google Sign In) despite the project saying that it should.

I must have activated this by accident when exploring the project setup process. The doesn't seem to be a way of deactivating this completely - only to switch between Google and OAuth.

Anyone successfully removed Account Linking from a project?

**Explanation from Google** re: failed submission due to this issue:

> During the review, we couldn’t find account creation / linking prompt, but your app uses GSI. Please provide more details in the testing instructions on how to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - but it's a bit hidden away. On the "Account Linking" page, you need to click the three-dot menu in the top right corner. Within that, choose "Clear" and your account linking settings will be reset and inactive.